# Events for keyboard appearing/disappearing on Android Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, keyboard, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there an event when the soft keyboard appears/disappears on Android Ice Cream Sandwich?  I remember that it was very difficult (or simply impossible) for an app running on Android Honeycomb tablets to find out when the soft keyboard was displayed or removed from the screen.  It was also impossible to modify the screen layout when the keyboard was on the screen.  Is this still true on Ice Cream Sandwich?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really changed with respect to IME behavior and IME interactions with activities in Android 4.0.